# Training requirements to work for the CAA in rulemaking

Tags: safety

For those who write regulations in the CAA, or part of the rulemaking process:
what sort of training do you require and how are these department structured?

I wanted to know more how the department responsible for rulemaking (CE 2) tasks are structured and what sort of training they normally require to enable them to  deliver sufficient and sound regulation for the CAA.

Comment: Which CAA to do you mean? For which country?

Comment: Civil Aviation Authorities (ICAO States)

Comment: You want to work for the FAA then, in the states it's not called the CAA.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the CAA in question to ask?

Comment: In Canada and I suspect most places they tend to be people recruited from the aviation industry with backgrounds in the operations, maintenance or engineering side.  I think you'll find the average employee at a regulator has a decade or more with an airline or an OEM as a tech, engineer, pilot, etc.

Comment: No 2 authorities will be the same, especially with how they're structured. As for training, they would typically have industry experience of some form, and then do specialist training as the CAA sees fit - such as regulatory processes and policy. The ones who write the final piece of regulation are lawyers.

Comment: They copy the bulk of the regulations from ICAO